# como hago para que cuando escriba en el buscador se abra otra pagina en la misma pero con las imagenes que quiero buscar?

Tags: javascript, html, css, buscador

Estoy creando mi propia paginas de peliculas online, estoy intentando hacer un buscador al estilo netflix, cuando escribis la pelicula en el buscador se habre otra pagina en la misma pero con la imagen de la pelicula que buscas es decir que cambia la pantalla sin cambiar la pagina https://www.netflix.com/search?q=a

ESPERO QUE COMPRENDAN LO QUE QUIERO HACER Y PUEDAN AYUDARME.

este es el codigo.

https://codepen.io/JheyMejia/pen/wQZKPz

si pongo este codigo en mi pagina no me sirve porque ya aparecen las imagenes , la idea es que esas imagenes esten ocultas y cuando escriba recien ahi aparezcan

Comment: Después de 3 años me doy cuenta que ese código en codepen es mío, me siento halagado (igual creo lo saqué de otro lado). Cualquier duda para futuros usuarios, pueden arrobarme y con gusto les colaboro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primero tienes que ocultar las peliculas desde el principio en css:

```
#myDIV .blog-inner {
  display: none;
}
```

Luego necesitas agregar otra condicion a tu filtro para evitar que las peliculas aparezcan cuando el valor del input es `empty string`.  Quedaria asi:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {    
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#myDIV .blog-inner").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().trim().indexOf(value) > -1 && value.length > 0)
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Gracias por responder, lo unico que faltaria es que se abra en otra pagina, asi no se ven mis contenedores de abajo

Comment: me sirvio tu respuesta pero le falto que se abra en la misma pagina pero con diferente pantalla, tipo asi  /search?q=HOLA